# Is it possible to make every class in a namespace automatically share the same mported namespaces?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces

So I've been programming with C# in Unity3D for awhile now, but never really took advantage of namespaces, so i am trying to fully understand them now. My question, more specifically, is "Can 'SharedNamespace' easily be shared across all namespaces that are part of the 'PrimaryNamespace'?"

I know this is possible by just adding the import statement within SecondaryNamespace and ThirdNamespace indvidually, but I am specifically asking if it can be done in the following manner with one import statement.

If this makes no sense let me know and I can try to explain it differently.

Thank you!

```
namespace SharedNamespace
{

}

namespace PrimaryNamespace
{
    using SharedNamespace;

    namespace SecondaryNamespace
    {

    }

    namespace ThirdNamespace
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It is very tedious to have to add the same import statements within sub-namespaces every time I need them, especially when there are tons of classes in the namespace. Would be lovely to just be able to apply the import statements to the primary namespace and avoid having to manually add it for each sub-namespace.

Comment: What text editor or IDE are you using? Some of them have great template capability so you could use a template for the classes in question.

Comment: @NikP Visual Studio 2017

Comment: [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-item-templates?view=vs-2019) discusses making file templates and might help you out.